# How to get enum order?

Tags: c#

If I have enum:

```
public enum ImportState : byte
{
     None = 0,
     ImportedWithChanges = 44,
     AwaitingApproval = 45,
     Removing = 66,
     Revalidating = 99,
};
```

How to get enum order?
For example:

```
GetOrder(ImportState.None)
```

Should return 1(first in order)

```
GetOrder(ImportState.AwaitingApproval )
```

Should return  3 (third in order)

Comment: You shouldn't think of enums as ordered since it would probably lead to a bad line of code somewhere.. what is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The further prove Sayse's point, the answers below will only work if your enum values are defined in numeric ascending order.  Otherwise, if you had defined `None = 100` for example, there would be no way to get the order of the constants properly.

Comment: My enum is some Workflow for all import states. I want create progress bar base on this enum. So if I have 10 values in enum, and first 3 are done, than it is 30% in my progress bar. My enum cannot have normal order 1,2,3.., because in future is possible that I will include new enum values.

Comment: @sstan It will be in numeric oreder. Must be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the missing method `GetOrder`

```
public static int GetOrder(ImportState State)
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(ImportState)).Cast<ImportState>().Select((x, i) => new { item = x, index = i }).Single(x => x.item == State).index;
}
```

Comment: Nice, simple, clean answer to question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As other noticed, `Enum.GetValues()` returns the values of an enum sorted by value. Perhaps this isn't what you wanted... So, using a little reflection:

```
public class EnumOrder<TEnum> where TEnum : struct
{
    private static readonly TEnum[] Values;

    static EnumOrder()
    {
        var fields = typeof(Values).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        Values = Array.ConvertAll(fields, x => (TEnum)x.GetValue(null));
    }

    public static int IndexOf(TEnum value)
    {
        return Array.IndexOf(Values, value);
    }
}
```

Example of use:

```
public enum Values
{
    Foo = 10,
    Bar = 1
}

int ix = EnumOrder<Values>.IndexOf(Values.Bar); // 1
```

Note that the C# specifications aren't clear if the "source code" ordering of an `enum` is maintained in the compiled program... At this time the C# compiler seems to maintain it, but there is no guarantee in the future...

The only two references I've found are:

> Forward declarations are never needed in C# because, with very few exceptions, declaration order is insignificant

and

> Declaration order for enum member declarations (§14.3) is significant when constant-expression values are omitted.

So as written, for the example I gave, the ordering is undefined and depends on the C# compiler!

Answer (score 1):

Enumerating the enum values, casting to an `IEnumerable`, converting to a `List`. This it is a simple matter of using `IndexOf()`.

Note that for this to work, the enum **must be declared in increasing order.**

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;

    class Program
    {
        public enum ImportState : byte
        {
            None = 0,
            ImportedWithChanges = 44,
            AwaitingApproval = 45,
            Removing = 66,
            Revalidating = 99,
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetOrder(ImportState.None));
            Console.WriteLine(GetOrder(ImportState.AwaitingApproval));
        }

        public static int GetOrder(ImportState state)
        {
            var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ImportState)).Cast<ImportState>().ToList();

            return enumValues.IndexOf(state) + 1; // +1 as the IndexOf() is zero-based
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
1
3
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Sth. like this?

```
int i = 0;
foreach (ImportState state in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ImportState)))
{
    i++;
    if (state == myState) return i;
}
```

However there is no real use for this, as enums do not provide an indexed enumeration in themselfes. They represent a value which is more what you´re probably after.

Comment: Yes! But I thought that there is something cleaner.

Comment: `Enum.GetValues(typeof(ImportState))` doesn't pay attention to line order in code and list enum values from minimal value to maximum. see demo https://dotnetfiddle.net/AfwNtt

Comment: What do you mean by "cleaner". Furthermore I guess that everone of us is interested why you need the indexed number within the ordered enumeration.

Comment: Note that the values returned from `Enum.GetValues()` will always be in increasing order, EVEN IF THE ENUM SPECIFIES THEM IN A DIFFERENT ORDER. This may be important.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this LINQ query:

```
int position = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ImportState)).Cast<ImportState>()
    //.OrderBy(impState => (int)impState)
    .TakeWhile(impState => impState != ImportState.None)
    .Count() + 1;
```

It orders by the int-value of the enum-value, then it takes all until the searched value and counts them. I have omitted the `OrderBy` since `Enum.GetValues` automatically returns the order according to their int-value.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The elements of the array are sorted by the binary values of the
>   enumeration constants

Comment: The values may not be in an increasing order. It's not clear from the question that this is what is wanted as OP may want the values in the order they are specified.

Comment: @DavidG: since OP specified those unusual values i suspected that this is what he wants. Otherwise it wouldnt make sense anyway.

Comment: I agree this is probably what he wants, I just think that in it's current form, it's a bad question.

Comment: @DavidG: i have found out an interesting detail. If i omit the `OrderBy` i get the same result even if i change the declaration order. It seems that `Enum.GetValues(typeof(ImportState))` orders by the value implicitely.

Comment: Just to make things even more odd, `GetValues` uses unsigned magnitude to order so if the OP hadn't used a `byte` enum, then `-100` would come at the end.

Comment: @DavidG: you're right, in that case it would be better to use the `OrderBy` that i've now commented out to ensure the _correct_ order.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the order, you would be better to make better use of the flags. Consider the following

```
public enum ImportState : byte
{
     None = 0,
     ImportedWithChanges = 2,
     AwaitingApproval = 4,       
     Removing = 6,
     Revalidating = 8,
};
(double)state / Enum.GetValues(typeof(ImportState)).Cast<byte>().Max()
```

[Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mug8Xu)

Enums don't really have any sense of ordering, using the above probably still isn't perfect but it doesn't involve a made up order.

Answer (score 0):

What about this Solution?

```
var result = from r in Enum.GetValues<ImportState>()
         let expression =
         r == ImportState.Revalidating
            ? 0
            : r == ImportState.AwaitingApproval
                ? 1
                : r == ImportState.Removing
                    ? 2
                    : r == ImportState.ImportedWithChanges
                        ? 3
                        : 4
         orderby expression ascending
         select r.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

Output: Revalidating, AwaitingApproval, Removing, ImportedWithChanges, None